# Is Django written with only Python?

Tags: python, django

I am suffering from `segmentation fault` while running `Django`.(It is just simple code with test server)

As I look for, `Django` is written with `Python`.

I want to make sure that if `Django` is written with only `python` without any `C libraries` or something that can generate segmentation fault so that I can say the segmentation fault is because of `Python interpreter` itself.

`Django` is written with only `python`?

**-------Eidt--------**

Some other python packages import C libraries directly in the packages for example `lxml`,`cx_Oracle`.

As a result, even if I install python perfectly, It can make segmentation fault accessing the third part `wrong C libraries`.

My Question is that If I install python perfectly, Django never generate segmentation fault ?

Because `Django` is only running on python interpreter not accessing directly third part C libraries.

I am suspicious that there must be something wrong while installing Python not django.(I am trying to install python in AIX)

Comment: Even if it was only written in python, are you using the C implementation of Python?  Most are.  Segmentation faults are extremely rare in python, it is more likely that you are using an external C library yourself.  Are you, for example, mixing 32-bit and 64-bit?

Comment: Whether it is or isn't won't really help solve your problem, you should ask about the actual problem you're trying to solve

Comment: Anything written in Python is ultimately also "written" in C because Python itself is written in C. If you have bug-related questions, then produce an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or file a bug report with the django project directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is just simple code with test server

Django itself is written entirely in python (plus a small amount of javascript and shell scripts).

Is django really the only python package installed though? It very rarely is, even for simple sites.

Many packages installed via pip are not pure python however (eg `mysqlclient-python`: 64% python/36% C code). Even if a package **is** pure python it might use `ctypes` to call C libraries directly (eg the `mysql-ctypes` package).

Even with a bug-free interpreter, a bug in a linked C library (eg `libmysql`) or a python package that contains/interfaces with C code can cause a segfault.

Answer (score 1):

Django is only Python, it has no C code. Some parts of it have dependencies to do use C, e.g. GeoDjango has dependencies written in C.

Add

```
import faulthandler
faulthandler.enable()
```

to your Django settings file, and hopefully it prints a stack trace that shows you where the crash is happening. See [this blog post](http://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2013/08/15/handy-tracebacks-with-faulthandler.html).

Edit: this does require you to `pip install faulthandler`, of course, if you aren't using Python 3.3 or newer/